# QGIS programmatically change outline colour of circles

Tags: qgis, python

I have a vector layer with a "Simple Marker" for the style. I see I can create Data Defined properties for both the colour and the outline colours.

In Python, I'm able to change the marker's base colour (for the data defined property), but I can't seem to find how to change the outline's colour.

Here's what I have:

```
symbols = layer.rendererV2().symbols()
symbol = symbols[0]

expr = 'color_rgba(255,0,0,0)'
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty('color', expr)

# I would expect this to work, but it doesn't
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty('outlineColor', expr)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From [Symbology of vector layers in QGIS Python Plugins](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) : "The names of available properties can be found using the properties method of an existing symbol layer: `symbol_layer.properties()`". Hopefully it will help you to find the right property name.

Comment: In this case, 'color_border' is the adequate property for color border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next code works [but I used 'color_rgba(255,0,0,255)' to avoid complete transparency]; where 'color_border' is the adequate property for color border.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

symbols = layer.rendererV2().symbols()

symbol = symbols[0]

expr = 'color_rgba(255,0,0,255)'
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty('color', expr)

# I would expect this to work, but it doesn't
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty('color_border', expr)

layer.triggerRepaint()

iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

Comment: 'color_border' - exactly what I needed, thanks! It was so hard to find and not at all intuitive.