# How to set label font color using data defined property for PyQGIS 3?

Tags: labeling, pyqgis-3

Set label font color using data defined property in PyQGIS 2 is well established, e.g. [in another thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210193/qgis-programmatically-change-outline-colour-of-circles/210210)

However, PyQGIS 3 completely changed the way this works with no well documented examples. So, how to setup labels whose colors are based on data defined property. Here is my initial try, the label text show up, but the label's font color is not changing as i specified to be dependent upon the 'color' field values:

```
prop=QgsProperty()
prop.setField("Color")
pc=QgsPropertyCollection('mycol')
pc.setProperty(0,prop)
pal_layer=QgsPalLayerSettings()
pal_layer.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)
pal_layer.fieldName="value"
pal_layer.enabled=True
labeler=QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(pal_layer)
layer.setLabeling(labeler)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the **size** property to take ownership of the field "Color" with this line:

```
pc.setProperty(0,prop)
```

The `0` key value is for size, `1` is for bold style etc. The value you want is `4`:

```
pc.setProperty(4,prop)
```

This will set the **colour** property to take the field as its expression:

[image: Label font colour]

Comment: thanks, that worked. I would really hope the first int argument for setProperty to be an enumeration type, it's kinda hard to remember 0 is for size and 4 is for color etc, plus is there documentation on this on the web?

Comment: @ForComment - Most welcome! Unfortunately, I could not find anything in terms of usage in any documentation or the QGIS API docs. I'm hoping these would be updated to reflect such properties :)

Answer (score 3):

as I do not have enough reputation, yet, to add a comment to the answer from Joseph, I have to add a new one.
As far as I understood, the intended use of `QgsPropertyCollection.setProperty()` is to use an enumeration value casted to integer (see the [setProperty](https://qgis.org/api/3.10/classQgsPropertyCollection.html#a6ff9fad22458c53615588581723111dd) documentation).

Therefore, I think the ultimate solution in this case would be something like:

```
pc.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Color, prop)
```

The list of available entries for the `QgsPalLayerSettings` is given in the `QgsPalLayerSettings.Property` enum [here](https://qgis.org/api/3.10/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#a7d8c0bc9cdbb0e4159a8071205790f9a).

I hope this helps.